# Can I create a triangle with just using CSS?

Tags: css

I have tried following css:

```
 .triangle:after {
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-top:1px;
    margin-left:2px;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid white;
}

.triangle:before {
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 12px solid transparent;
    border-right: 12px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 12px solid black;
}
```

As i dont want to go with the SVG, is there any alternate way to achieve this.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your CSS provides what you are asking for. Is there something wrong with it? If so what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following css:

```
.triangle {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 100px solid #0099ff;
border-left: 100px dashed transparent;
border-right: 100px dashed transparent;
border-bottom: 0;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

You  can check this demo http://leplay.github.com/demo/triangle.html